# condition number

Tags: matrices, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Hi
I have the following matrix

A=[a_11   a_12   a_13   1;
   a_21   a_22   a_23   1;
     .
     .
     .
   a_n1   a_n2  a_n3   1]

I have seen that when some of a_ij are big for instance in the order of 200 , then condition
number is also big.

I would like to know is it possible to show it theoretically.

Is it possible to find a lower bound for this problem?

Regards,

Reza

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number discusses lower bounds for the condition number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to proceed would be to get the singular value decomposition of your matrix and then look at the ratio of the largest singular value to the smallest singular value (a.k.a. the 2-norm condition number); largeness of this condition number implies largeness of the condition number with respect to the other norms of interest, and you can probably just manipulate inequalities at that point.

Answer (score 4):

Having large entries is not related at all to the condition number. For example, the matrix $10,000I$ (ten thousand times the identity) has condition number 1. One can easily generate matrices with arbitrarily large and small entries (even at the same time) and condition number 1.

In order to prove a bound, you need to exploit some more structural properties of the matrix you are working with.